# How to play video in sencha touch

Tags: video, sencha-touch

I want to play video in my sencha touch app .. 
Kindly help me if anyone knows about this..

Sample

```
{
    xtype: 'video',
    // cls: 'video',
    url: 'lib/sample.mp4',
    loop: false,
    width: 250,
    height: 10,
    posterUrl: 'lib/touch/img/pic2.jpg'
}
```

Comment: Your code looks fine. What problem are you having? It isn't showing? Is the poster/component showing? Are you sure the URL is correct?

Comment: Yes poster component is there ,, But when i click on the poster it got black with crossed play icon

Comment: Do i need to import other library to play video or not

Comment: That means the video is not in a format the browser can play. You must format it before playing it.

Comment: Well i have tried .mp4 and .mov but no success ..

Comment: Have you tried playing the video directly in the browser? The ST component simply uses the HTML5 `<video>` tag - so if it works in the browser, it should work there.

Comment: Ok the issue is resolved thanks for assistance

Comment: Hi rdougna r u there ? I need some help regarding sencha touch

Answer (score 1):

If you include the poster attribute on the video tag when you’re using  tags, the video won’t work on iPads & iPhones using iOS 3. You’ll see a broken play button, or no play button at all.

But apparently this bug was fixed in iOS 4

For more information regarding video, refer to site below.
http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody#notes